# Toggle shipping method based on customer's condition

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, shipping-methods, mod-rewrite

I created an extension following [Inchoo's tutorial](http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/) but still confusing at how to toggle the shipping method.

Once customers about to see the shipping method page, I need to check the customer's attribute. If *Yes* the display my custom shipping method, otherwise hide. This is required for both frontend and admin placing order.

I have a few thoughts but all out of my ability to start. I need some hints about which idea is the most efficient and what files should I created:

1. Using ***event***: set an event such as *`before_shipping_method_render`(I made up this one)*, then I can setup a function in `Observer.php` to remove the shipping method from the collection before rendering but I don't know the event name and how to get the collection.
2. Rewriting Magento function: rewrite the function that puts all enabled shipping methods together. I can put my condition check function in the iterate then allow my custom shipping method if condition is *Yes* otherwise vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

Update your module's config.xml file with the following details:

```
<global>
        <blocks>
            <checkout>
                <rewrite>
                    <onepage_shipping_method_available>Inchoo_Shipping_Block_Method</onepage_shipping_method_available>
                </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </blocks>
<global>
```

Create a new file Inchoo/Shipping/Block/Method.php, which remove your shipping method:

```
<?php
class Inchoo_Shipping_Block_Method extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available
{
    public function getShippingRates()
    {
        $youCustomAttribute = false;
        // Check if any customer is logged in or not
        if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {  
            // Load the customer's data
            $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();   
            // mange your code to get the customer attribute 
            $youCustomAttribute = $customer->getYourCustomerAttribute();

        }
        $rates = parent::getShippingRates();
        if (array_key_exists('inchoo_shipping', $rates) && $youCustomAttribute!==false) {
            unset($rates['inchoo_shipping']);
        }

        return $rates;
    }
}
```

For more see [here.](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/hide-other-shipping-methods-when-free-shipping-is-enabled/)